# What are the names of 56 Bhog offered to Lord Krishna?

Tags: scripture, krishna, belief, food

[This page](http://www.pinkjooz.com/index.php/the-story-of-chappan-bhog-56-food-offerings/) says

> As per Hindu beliefs, Lord Krishna used to have 8 meals per day. Once to save his village from the fury of Lord Indra, he lifted the Govardhan Parvat (Mountain) under which everyone took refuge. He remained in the task continuously for 7 days until Indra gave up after realizing his mistake. Further, the villagers offered him `56(8x7)` food items to compensate for what He had missed.

What are the names of 56 Bhog offered to Lord Krishna?
Is it mentioned in Hindu scriptures?